# Find string & Replace with backspace

Tags: regex, netbeans, replace

I'm using an IDE - in my case, Netbeans, but my question is more general I suppose - and I have the following:

```
html
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

This structure is repeated throughout the CSS file; the opening curly brace is on a separate line.
What I want is this:

```
html{
margin: 0px;
}
```

Basically, I want to match all opening curly braces on a line and move them to the end of the preceding line.

I matched them in regex with this:

```
^\{$
```

But I don't know how to fill the Replace box with "*backspace once and then {*"

Apparently backspace is ASCII 8, but I can't figure out how to enter an ASCII code.

Any way to do this, ASCII or not?

---

I figured it out:

Find this:

```
(.)\n\{
```

Replace with this:

```
$1{
```

Find any character followed by a new line and opening brace,
Replace with that character and an opening brace (via group referring)

Answer (score 2):

This one works too :

```
\r\n{
```

replaced by

```
{
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups instead

Match: `(\w+)\s*\{`

Replace With: `$1{`

Comment: Illegal Repetition, it says.

Comment: @user2000356 checked it..you need to escape `{` with `\{`

Comment: I used a combination of your method (referring to a group) with a different match, please check my reply to myself. Thanks for showing me how to refer to groups! (regex noob here.)

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to understand is that you need to match and replace *characters*, not *keystrokes*. In your case that means you want to replace character-newline-curlybrace with character-curlybrace.

The expression you can search on is `(.)\n\{`, and you want to replace it with `$1{`

For those using other languages you might need to use `\1` instead of `$1`, which represents whatever character matched `(.)`.

Comment: Yup, I edited my question yesterday to post the same method after figuring it out.